# Watch out for C function names with R code

Tags: c, r

So here is something a bit crazy.

If you have some C code which is called by an R function (as a shared object), try adding this to the code

```
void warn() {

 int i; // just so the function has some work, but you could make it empty to, or do other stuff

}
```

If you then call `warn()` anywhere in the C code being called by the R function you get a segfault;

```
  *** caught segfault ***
 address 0xa, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:
  1: .C("C_function_called_by_R", as.double(L), as.double(G), as.double(T), as.integer(nrow),     as.integer(ncolL), as.integer(ncolG), as.integer(ncolT),     as.integer(trios), as.integer(seed), as.double(pval), as.double(pval1),     as.double(pval2), as.double(pval3), as.double(pval4), as.integer(ntest),     as.integer(maxit), as.integer(threads), as.integer(quietly))
  2: package_name::R_function(L, G, T, trios)
  3: func()
  4: system.time(func())
  5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
  6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
  7: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  8: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste(prefix, "\n  ", sep = "")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n", sep = "")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
  9: try(system.time(func()))
 10: .executeTestCase(funcName, envir = sandbox, setUpFunc = .setUp,     tearDownFunc = .tearDown)
 11: .sourceTestFile(testFile, testSuite$testFuncRegexp)
 12: runTestSuite(testSuite)
 aborting ...
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
 (END)
```

Needless to say the code runs fine if you call the same function from a C or C++ wrapper instead of from an R function. If you rename `warn()` it also works fine.

Any ideas? Is this a protected name/symbol? Is there a list of such names? I'm using R version 2.14.1 on Ubuntu 12.01 (i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)). C code is compiled with GNU GCC  4.6.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like quite an interesting question. Here's my minimal example, in a file `test.c` I have

```
void warn() {}
void my_fun() { warn(); }
```

I compile it and then run

```
$ R CMD SHLIB test.c
$ R -e "dyn.load('test.so'); .C('my_fun')"
```

With my linux gcc version 4.6.3., the R output is

```
> dyn.load('test.so'); .C('my_fun')
R: Success
list()
```

with that "R: Success" coming from the `warn` function defined in libc (see `man warn`, defined in err.h). What happens is that R loads several dynamic libraries as a matter of course, and then loads test.so as instructed. When my_fun gets called, the dynamic linker resolves `warn`, but the rules of resolution are to search *globally* for the `warn` symbol, and not just in test.so. I really don't know what the global search rules are, perhaps in the order the .so's were opened, but whatever the case the resolution is not where I was expecting.

What is to be done? Specifying

```
static void warn() {}
```

forces resolution at compile time, when the .o is created, and hence avoiding the problem. This wouldn't work if, for instance, `warn` was defined in one file (utilities.c) and `my_fun` in another. On Linux `dlopen` (the function used to load a shared object) can be provided with a flag `RTLD_DEEPBIND` that does symbol resolution locally before globally, but (a) R does not use `dlopen` that way and (b) there are [several](http://smilax.org/135/dsohowto.pdf) (see p. 9) reservations with this kind of approach. So as far as I can tell the best practice is to use `static` where possible, and to carefully name functions to avoid name conflicts. This latter is not quite as bad as it seems, since R loads package shared objects such that the package symbols themselves are NOT added to the global name space (see `?dyn.load` and the `local` argument, and also note the OS-specific caveats).

I'd be interested in hearing of a more robust 'best practice'.